# Authenticate with only username

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-forms, django-views

I creating quiz app, in which user login with only username and the proceed for a quiz but django authenticate not working
views.py

```
class UserFormView(View):
form_class = UserForm
template_name = 'app/registration_form.html'

def get(self, request):
    form = self.form_class(None)
    return render(request, self.template_name, {'form': form})

def post(self, request):
    form = self.form_class(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        user = form.save(commit=False)
        # cleaned data
        username = form.cleaned_data['username']
        user.save()
        # autheticate
        user = authenticate(username=username)
        if user is not None:
            if user.is_active:
                login(request, user)
                return redirect('app:quiz_list')
            else:
                return HttpResponse('active nahi hai')
        else:
            return HttpResponse('pehchan me nahi hai')

    return render(request, self.template_name, {'form': form})
```

Comment: So, what would happen if two (or more) people log in with the same *username* at the *same time*?

Comment: There is not much of sense of not having any credentials as anyone can hijack any account, even if it is random generated it is still not secure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using default authentication backend it requires **username** and **password**

You can create a custom authentication backend yourself by following related [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/auth/customizing/#writing-an-authentication-backend)

Considering you are not really authenticating you can just filter user from database and use login function afterwards

```
#TODO add exception if there is no user with username
user = User.objects.filter(username=username).get()
login(request, user)
```